# Android set html content to textView with HtmlTextView class

Tags: android, textview

today i'm find this class to define any html tag for android widgets. but after download and create new instance from it i can not set that to TextView. i'm search in class document but i can not find any document about how to set class result to TextView:

```
HtmlTextView text = new HtmlTextView(this);
text.setHtmlFromString("<h2>Hello wold</h2><ul><li>cats</li><li>dogs</li></ul>", true);

/* Set text to content  */
content.setText ( text );
```

Comment: what you wanna achieve ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ set content text as `text.setHtmlFromString ...`

Comment: are you using this ? https://github.com/dschuermann/html-textview

Comment: @SweetWisherツ yes sir.

Comment: then why you want it in TextView ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ i want to set any html tag into TextView. after testing Html.fromHtml i know thats could not view `<a>` as an html link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66009/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-andbee).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
content.setText(Html.fromHtml("Your Html String"));
```

Comment: i want to use HtmlTextView class.

Comment: You are using a custom view.. no one can help you much with this.